# Python: Higher Order Functions with Methods

Tags: python, higher-order-functions

In Python, is there anyway to pass a method to a higher order function, as you would if passing a regular function?

For example, let's say I have a string, "str", and depending on some condition, "cond", I want to apply some arbitrary method, "meth", to the string and return it. In code:

```
def func(str, meth, cond):
    ...
    if cond:
        str.meth()
    ...
```

Now, I know the above doesn't work. I also know that I could write something like:

```
def func(str, meth, cond):
    ...
    if cond:
        str = meth
    ...
```

and pass the object and method I want to execute to func like this: func(str, str.capitalize(), cond). The problem with the above is that:

1. The above code doesn't make the intention of the function clear.
2. If I, for example, want to modify "str" in anyway before the application of the method, then I end up with an incorrect result. Consider:

   ```
   def func(str, meth, cond):
       ...
       str += "a"
       ...
       if cond:
           str = meth
       ...
   ```

   will not work as intended.

So, returning to the beginning: is there anyway to accomplish what I want? Or am I approaching this from the wrong direction altogether?

Comment: I think besides explaining what you are intending to implement it, you should also give more examples on how you wanna use this `func`?

Comment: What are you intending `str = meth` to do?  I have a hunch you're looking for [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass a method to a higher order function just like you would any function, you just have to pass it as `object.method`:

```
class Foo(object):
    def upper(self, s):
        return s.upper()

def func(s, method, cond):
    if cond:
        return method(s)
    else:
        return s

obj = Foo()
s = 'hello world'

print(func(s, obj.upper, 'hello' in s))   
print(func(s, obj.upper, 'goodbye' in s))
```

result:

```
HELLO WORLD
hello world
```

Or alternatively if you might try:

```
def func(s, method, cond):
    if cond:
        return method()
    else:
        return s

s = 'hello world'

print(func(s, s.upper, 'hello' in s))
print(func(s, s.upper, 'goodbye' in s))
```

However, as pointed out in the comments, this second approach won't work if you have a statement as `s = s + 'a'` inside the function, since you are just binding the local variable `s` to a new string, while `method` is still bound to the `upper` method of the string initially passed to the function.

Comment: Does the second alternative you suggest with the "s.upper" work in the scenario where the string is modified inside "func" before calling the method?

Comment: No, that is a really good point. Strings are immutable so if you perform `s = s + 'a'` you are just binding the local variable `s` to a new string, but `method` is still bound to `s.upper` of the old string without the extra 'a'.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you what is to pass meth as an unbounded method, so it can be bounded to another object dynamicly.

```
>>> class C(object):
...     def foo(self):
...             print self
... 
>>> C.foo
<unbound method C.foo>
>>> C().foo
<bound method C.foo of <__main__.C object at 0xb708216c>>
>>> def func(obj, meth):
...     meth(obj)
... 
>>> c = C()
>>> func(c, C.foo)
<__main__.C object at 0xb70822ac>
>>> c
<__main__.C object at 0xb70822ac>
```

you can think an unbounded method as an regular who must take an object as its first argument

Answer (score 0):

This does not allow you to call the function *exactly* as you wanted but it gets really close so perhaps it solves your problem.

```py
def func(str, meth, cond):
    if cond:
        str = getattr(str, meth)()
    return str

print func("a", "capitalize", True)
print func("a", "capitalize", False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't quite sure what you're asking, but you could pass a function like the following.

```
def func(str, meth, cond):
    ...
    ...
    if cond:
        return meth(str)
    ...
```

And run it like this: (for example lowercase)

```
func("ABC", str.lower, True)
```

should return `"abc"`